# Excel VBA - Analysing Shared Mailbox Outlook - Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the following code in Excel to try to get the details from our shared mailbox into a spreadsheet for further analysis.

The code produces a run-time error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error at the point it reaches trying to get the Sender, SenderEmailAddress & SenderName.

It is fine when these parts are made inactive and it gets the Subject, ReceivedTime, etc without any issue.

Does anyone know what needs to be changed to get that working?

Also, does anyone have any suggestions on how to loop through all of the folders in the shared mailbox instead of having to set-up a Case selection for each folder in the mailbox hierarchy?  Or even a shorter way of adding the folders required (i.e. one line of code for each folder vs 2/3/4 lines)?

Thanks in advance

```
Sub getEmails()

Dim olApp       As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS        As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr      As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItem      As Object
Dim olMailItem  As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim iRow        As Long
Dim hdr         As Variant
Dim iFldr       As Long
Dim lstAtt      As String
Dim olAtt       As Outlook.Attachment
Dim dlm         As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

With ws
    iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For iFldr = 1 To 2
    Select Case iFldr
        Case 1
            Set olFldr = olNS.Folders(1)
            Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("Inbox")
            'Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("Access Requests")
            'Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("Ad-hoc Requests")
        Case 2
            Set olFldr = olNS.Folders(1)
            Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("Inbox")
            Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("Folders")
        Case Else
    End Select

    For Each olItem In olFldr.Items
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set olMailItem = olItem
                iRow = iRow + 1
            With olMailItem
                If Not .Sender Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(iRow, "D") = .Subject
                ws.Cells(iRow, "A") = .Sender
                ws.Cells(iRow, "B") = .SenderEmailAddress
                ws.Cells(iRow, "C") = .SenderName

                ws.Cells(iRow, "E") = .ReceivedTime
                ws.Cells(iRow, "F") = .Categories
                ws.Cells(iRow, "G") = .TaskCompletedDate
                ws.Cells(iRow, "H") = olFldr.Name
                lstAtt = ""
                dlm = ""
                For Each olAtt In .attachments
                    lstAtt = lstAtt & dlm & olAtt.DisplayName
                    dlm = ";" 'Chr(10)
                Next
                ws.Cells(iRow, "I") = lstAtt
            End With
        End If
    Next olItem
Next iFldr


With ws
    hdr = Array("Sender", "SenderEmailAddress", "SenderName", "Subject", "ReceivedTime", "Categories", "TaskCompletedDate", "Folder", "Attachments")
    .Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(hdr)) = hdr
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox "Complete!"
```

End Sub

[image: Locals Window view]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably here;

```
If Not .Sender Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(iRow, "D") = .Subject
ws.Cells(iRow, "A") = .Sender
```

If the sender is not null, you're writing the subject to column D. Then, regardless of whether the sender is null or not, you're trying to write the sender to column A. That's going to throw an error when it is null.

The fix for it will really depend on what you're trying to achieve. If you don't want to output any mail items with a null sender (these will typically be draft or deleted mail that wasn't sent), just include everything in the `If Not .Sender is Nothing` check.

```
With olMailItem
    If Not .Sender Is Nothing Then
        iRow = iRow + 1
        ws.Cells(iRow, "D") = .Subject
        ws.Cells(iRow, "A") = .Sender
        ws.Cells(iRow, "B") = .SenderEmailAddress
        ws.Cells(iRow, "C") = .SenderName

        ws.Cells(iRow, "E") = .ReceivedTime
        ws.Cells(iRow, "F") = .Categories
        ws.Cells(iRow, "G") = .TaskCompletedDate
        ws.Cells(iRow, "H") = olFldr.Name
        lstAtt = ""
        dlm = ""
        For Each olAtt In .Attachments
            lstAtt = lstAtt & dlm & olAtt.DisplayName
            dlm = ";" 'Chr(10)
        Next
        ws.Cells(iRow, "I") = lstAtt
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks John for looking at this.  Yes I am looking to avoid any output of any mail items with a null sender.  I still get the same issue when I move the parts around so when listing the above in column order.

Comment: In VBA, if you put a value on the same line as an `If` statement, that `If` only applies to that single line. I'm not saying to just move things around, I'm saying to include everything inside that `If` condition where you check whether the mail item actually has a sender. Right now, `If Not .Sender Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(iRow, "D") = .Subject` only applies to that single line; everything else is happening regardless of whether there's a sender or not, and this is throwing an error when there's not a sender.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer.  What I meant was, I have changed it to what you placed above and instead of Subject being the first line, I have moved it to between C and E.  The result is the same issue as before.

Comment: Have you looked at the debug info? It's passing the `If Not .Sender is nothing` condition, then throwing an error at the `ws.Cells(iRow, "A") = .Sender` line?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  It is that line at which it falls down.

Comment: Have you looked at the Locals window when in debug mode? Does the MailItem in question actually have a sender?

Comment: First time looking at the Locals window!  OK, so next to Sender in Value column it is blank with Type = AddressEntry/AddressEntry.  I guess perhaps for easier understanding for myself, taking just the SenderEmailAddress it shows value as <>, Type = String.  Does this suggest that there is nothing to pick up here then as I guess the value column would have an email address in there but doesn't hence why it fails?

Comment: What it means is going to be dependent on what kind of mail you're looking at. Look at the subject when in debug mode, then find the corresponding mail item in outlook; check whether it's something you're actually looking to include in your output, or whether you need to update your `if` condition to look at something other than `if not .Sender is nothing` (for example, checking `if .SenderEmailAddress <> "<>"`).

Comment: OK.  I am looking to get who sent the email to the shared mailbox in the analysis.  I have made inactive the    If Not.Sender Is Nothing Then line and the next     End If but it still gets stuck at the same line.

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.Sender` returns an object (`AddressEntry`), not a scalar value (string or an int). You are already accessing `SenderEmailAddress` and `SenderName`, why do you need Sender?

Also, you are assuming that the first store is always the default mailbox. That is not always the case. Use `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` instead.

Comment: hi Dmitry.  Actually per my first post, neither SenderEmailAddress, SenderName or Sender are returning anything as the same issue is present on all of those.  As for your second point, thanks.  It is pointing to the mailbox required using the above.  Is there a solution to the issue being faced of not being able to bring in either the Sender, SenderEmailAddress or the SenderName?

Comment: Does this error happen on the very first item you process or only after you process a few of them?

Comment: Happens on the first one and all subsequent ones when I manually move the code on to process the loop.