# Logging SenderName and Body using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to log data points from an Outlook folder into Excel.

Pasting the email's Subject and Date into the Excel ranges works but not SenderName and Body.

I get an application define or object error when it reaches

`Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.SenderName`

```vb
Sub GetOutlookData()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim FolderItems As Items

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("FOLLOWUPS")
Set Folder = Folder.Folders("Inbox")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items

    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date") Then
        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Body
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I just ran a slightly modified version of your code and didn't get the run-time error you mention. Do you get the error on the very first `OutlookMail` loop or does it work for a few items before giving the error? If it's on the first loop, what if you skip that element (by changing the date in range `email_Receipt_Date` for example)?

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377064/excel-vba-analysing-shared-mailbox-outlook-run-time-error-1004-application)

Comment: @DecimalTurn It is in the very first OutlookMail loop. One thing that I notice from the question you raised is that this is a shared folder, so while it might work on a normal outlook, it doesn't seem to work on shared email folders. Any idea why?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have experience with shared folder, so I can't really help you if that's the issue. Have you tried running your code on a non-shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming you can only have `MailItem` objects in the Inbox folder, bu you can also have `ReportItem` and `MeetingItem` objects.

Check first that you have a MailItem object :

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
  if OutlookMail.Class = 43 Then 'olMail
    ...
```